# Sort songs within an Apple Music Playlist - by Artist, Song Name, etc

Tags: ios, itunes, apple-music, playlist

There was a [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/7yk20q/i_figured_out_how_to_sort_songs_within_an_apple/) about tracks sorting within an playlist in Apple Music app for iOS but it seems this method doesn't work anymore (at least for me).

When I delete or add songs to playlists using iTunes, yes, it automatically syncs with my iPhone (Apple Music app) but sorting seems to be ignored, whichever sorting/order I set in iTunes it doesn't reflect in Apple Music app.

How can I solve this problem?

I just want to sort my track by *release date*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the way (but still you need iTunes to set order on your iOS device).

- Open iTunes
- Right click on a playlist
- Select **Copy to Play Order** to set the default order for this playlist when copied to a device

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The really BIG question is why does apple not have this oh so basic capability.   Sort by title / artist / album.   Once again we have the toy computer philosophy.